# Logcat data not displaying in the Log Tab of DDMS Eclipse

Tags: android, logcat, ddms, android-logcat

1. The log tab is visible in DDMS and I have been logging data using Log.v(...) for many a week now without any problems.
2. Today, the log data is now longer being displayed in the Log window.  Worked, then did a programming change to track a bug and now the log data is no longer showing.
3. Have tried running the app on an external Android phone, on the Android Simulator and it makes no difference.
4. Have closed  down Eclipse, reloaded and still no change.
5. The console displays activity but only to the point of starting the activity.
6. The external phone is set up for debugging - not that this could be a problem since I have the same problem with the simulator

It looks like I have inadvertantly set something incorrectly but can't remember changing anything :-(

Anyone come across this problem before - have looked at previous posts but none seem relevant.

Regards,

Oliver

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I had the same problem a while back. I was using the emulator and device for debugging. Apparently you have to select the device listed in the DDMS view whose logs you want to see. My logs were blank because the device that I was expecting logs from was not the one selected.

Hope that helps

Comment: Yup, that was the cause ... now all happy in programming and debugging land :-)

Comment: but in device can't display the devices.

Answer (score 1):

Tried this:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/9826502/1238317

> Check in your logcat window - TOP RIGHT corner PAUSE button || (Pause
>   receiving new logcat messages)
>
> Few clicks + eventually restart eclipse (usually works in my case)

Answer (score 0):

Check your LogCat window to see if you are filtering and make sure to set the debug level to Verbose.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the tip, it was a device selection problem as highlighted earlier in the thread - but thanks again for your time.

Answer (score 0):

There are possible reasons and solutions:

- LogCat might have to much in cache, clear the log and see if it fixed the issue
- You might need to select the device in the device view (even if it is already selected, try to click on it)
- adb is not correctly working anymore, try to kill and start it again

Check if you see output if you use the command line `adb logcat`

Comment: Thanks for the tips, it turned out that I had not the correct device selected as per previous thread.

Answer (score 0):

Just go to DDMS perspective and click on the device's name in upper left corner and done your log cat will Start with a BOOm :P

Answer (score 0):

In **Android Studio**, which I have found to be much more reliable and intuitive than Eclipse, I found this to be a common issue. For me what solves it (device is automatically set when running your app) besides checking code, is to **Quit and restart the emulator** or **Quit Android Studio and Emulator and reopen/restart**