# i never see the logcat output in android emulator?

Tags: android, emulation, ddms

i want see the console output so i use the Logcat but the logcat is not display any output messages. i also restart  eclipse.also click on devices log in android DDMS.i also do the Reset All perspective of DDMS.but i can`t success.

Comment: Had the same problem. Restarted eclipse leaving emulator running and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Select the device/emulator in DDMS when its in online mode.And there is `'+'` sign(green coloured) in left panel under `"Saved Filters"` of the LogCat.Click it and add your whole `package name` in `"Filter Name"` and `"by Application Name"`.Try this.

Comment: Sorry I do this type but can`t success

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that in your Logcat the buttons to the top right aren't selected. One of them blocks the Logcat to display new logs. Hope that helps.

Comment: what level of log is selected? verbose, debug, error, assert? maybe that could be the cause.

Comment: i also try one bye one but can`t success.i ask you another question

Comment: found this but could not be sure that helps because i never had the problem. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5623182/logcat-data-not-displaying-in-the-log-tab-of-ddms-eclipse

Comment: i also want  give the answer of any question which posted in current time.how to find this?

Comment: i don't get it. you want to see all new questions? simple, select newest tab.