# Eclipse Stop Showing Logs

Tags: android, eclipse

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Logcat not displaying my log calls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4228641/logcat-not-displaying-my-log-calls)

I am developing an Android Application, Here I am using Eclipse Galelio for Development. Whenever I want to debug, I use `Log.i ( TAG, "message" )` to check the execution details. Here after sometime, Eclipse stops to show those details. So I want to know why it is stopping from showing log details ? In such situation, If I restart my Eclipse then it is again start showing logs for few times. As I am checking logs for AutoStart Application. I need to close the Emualtor/Phone & then restarting it. Does this effect to Eclipse Log ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps this will fix your problem?

https://stackoverflow.com/a/4228815/210070

I've had the issue as well and clearing the log has worked for me.