# Why does Logcat not show all system messages?

Tags: android, logcat

I try to debug my Android home screen widget using `Logcat` but for some reasons not all the messages are showing up in the log, why is that?

Sometimes I can see the system intent, sometimes not all my `Log.d()` strings are shown in the log.

I'm using the standard `Logcat` view from within Eclipse, `Logcat` is in verbose and I don't have any filters.

**Edit:**
Maybe I wasn't clear in my question. Logcat shows stuff in its "console" it is just that some entries seem to be missing. Is it normal for example that the system Intent and my own (the one I create) are not shown or not all shown?

Comment: Are you seeing all (or any) of your own log items, or only system-level logs?

Comment: have you checked all the V,D,I,W buttons there? on the LogCat tab page window? Like here on the image http://www.droidnova.com/debugging-in-android-using-eclipse,541.html/debugging-2

Comment: Make sure you select the correct device from the devices view
http://stackoverflow.com/a/2945333/771300

Comment: What does happen when you run `logcat` from the cmd line? (`adb logcat`)

Comment: Now a days it has auto filtering..please see and remove that

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear in my question. Logcat shows stuff in its "console" it is just that some entries seem to be missing. Is it normal for example that the system Intent and my own (the one I create) are not shown?

Answer (score 0):

I think its a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4228641/logcat-not-displaying-my-log-calls).
From the answer by [ddewaele](https://stackoverflow.com/users/492410/ddewaele), Did you try this?

> When using Eclipse, in the DDMS perspective, make sure the correct
>   device (propably emulator-xxxx) is selected and highlighted. Only then
>   will you get the logcat output in the logcat view.
>
> Also, the Android plugin is a bit quircky, and sometimes only shows
>   the last line in the logcat view. If this happens, try to clear the
>   log. After that, you should get all the log entries again (works for
>   me anyway).

Comment: no it isnt a duplicate. The problem here is that NOT ALL records show up. This means that log records are shown but some of them are not though they should ve been shown