# Why won't my logs be displayed in the logcat?

Tags: android, eclipse, adb, logcat

I'm using Eclipse Indigo and up until just a couple hours ago or so everything was working fine. When I just relaunched it and made a couple changes, I ran the program on my phone but my logs were not being displayed. The phone's logs are displayed in the logcat, but nothing from the project is. I have the device selected, I've tried restarting eclipse multiple times, I've reset the ADB, and I've run the commands adb usb and adb logcat (which still doesn't display my logs). I know my logs are correct: Log.e("Tag","Message"); Anyone have any other ideas?

Comment: Did you select you app in the list of apps on the device?

Comment: Are you sure the log statements are executed? Try adding log at the beginning and also try adding a filter on tag name in logcat.

Comment: please see following answers:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4228641/logcat-not-displaying-my-log-calls
or
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2250112/why-doesnt-logcat-show-anything-in-my-android

hope it works for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, it was a stupid error on my part. I had my logs set up as: Log.e("Tag","") instead of: Log.e("","Message"). Apparently, if you have the former, it won't display to the LogCat, go figure?

Comment: You really should use both arguments - one to identify the component that is doing the logging, the other to give the message.

Comment: Why? If i know what it is and it's only temporary, what does it matter?

Answer (score 0):

I think, you haven't selected device or emulator , on which running your application,

In eclipse go to **DDMS Perspective** and **select device or emulator on which you are running your application.**

**(Note: No need to restart the Eclipse)**