# LogCat not showing the log despite the correct device being selected in DDMS perspective

Tags: android, android-logcat

The LogCat has stopped showing logs despite the right device being selected in DDMS perspective. I've tried restarting adb as well, and still not showing.

Comment: restart eclipse and see..

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

Close your LogCat tab and re-open it. To do this go to 'Window' menu option and select 'Show View' and then 'Other...'. A window opens and you will find LogCat under the 'Android' folder. Select this and your LogCat window tab will re-appear and this should display your logs.

Edit:
If this doesn't work restarting eclipse will be your other option.

Comment: Did you try this link - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4228641/logcat-not-displaying-my-log-calls?rq=1